# custom post type edit / publish hook

Tags: custom-post-types

What hook gets called when I edit or publish a custom post type of name 'episode gallery' ?

I tried following but none worked.

```
add_action('save_post', 'update_custom_ngg_table');
add_action('update_postmeta', 'update_custom_ngg_table');
add_action('publish_post', 'update_custom_ngg_table');
add_action('edit_post', 'update_custom_ngg_table');
add_action('edit_page', 'update_custom_ngg_table');
add_action('publish_page', 'update_custom_ngg_table');
add_action('save_page', 'update_custom_ngg_table');
add_action('publish_episode-gallery', 'update_custom_ngg_table');
```

I am about to give up :)

Answer (score 7):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you want {$new_status}_{my-custom-post-type}

Take a look at the [hook registration](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/%7B%24new_status%7D_%7B%24post-%3Epost_type%7D).

[This page (from Pippin's Posts)](http://pippinspages.com/tutorials/publish-action-hook-for-custom-post-types/)<sup>*</sup> does a better job than I could at explaining it, but from your example, you would want `add_action('publish_episode-gallery', 'update_custom_ngg_table');`

According to the source, the following status are available:
publish, future, draft, pending, private, trash, auto-draft and inherit.

<sup>* *[Mirror at the Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20101220235729/http://pippinspages.com/tutorials/publish-action-hook-for-custom-post-types/)*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It's always save_post, no matter what the post type. save_post also runs when creating and publishing a new post.

From inside your hooked function you can figure out what kind of post is being handled--it gets passed both the post id and the entire post object.

```
function wpsx_5688_update_post($post_id, $post) {

    // Make sure the post obj is present and complete. If not, bail.
    if(!is_object($post) || !isset($post->post_type)) {
        return;
    }

    switch($post->post_type) { // Do different things based on the post type

        case "episode-gallery":
            // Do your episode gallery stuff
            break;

        case "another-post-type-slug":
            // Do other stuff
            break;

        default:
            // Do other stuff

    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'wpsx_5688_update_post', 1, 2);
```

Another thing to consider is that--depending on your exact problem, I'm not sure what you're trying to do--it might not be that the hook isn't firing, but that the code inside your hooked function has errors. Just something else to check if you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an action when any custom post Edit/insert-

```
add_action('save_post','save_post_callback');
function save_post_callback($post_id){
global $post; 
if ($post->post_type != 'MY_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_NAME'){
    return;
}
//if you get here then it's your post type so do your things....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a change to a *specific* post type, you can also use the `save_post_$this->post_type` [hook documented here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type).

```php
$post_type = "enter_your_post_type_name_here";
add_action( 'save_post_' . $post_type, function( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Anything inside this function will run when the specified post type is updated.
} );
```