# Adding second Email address for WP user notifications

Tags: users, email, wp-mail

The WP systems sends a lot of mails to authors. There also plugins who use email notifications for authors.

But, let say I have a user, who is managed by two persons (because it's a company, an entity that is more then one person) - I want all the emails to be sent also to a second Email address, that I will enter in the profile page of that WP user.

What is the best way to achieve this? I know how to add a field to the profile page, but I don't know how to send every notification that the user gets to the second email address.
please help :)

Comment: Have you tried using comma separated values for the email? Just a thought...

Comment: tried it, just for the elimination process. it didn't worked.

Comment: What exactly didn't work out?

Comment: @kaiser, try it yourself - it would output an error saying it is not a valid email address.

Comment: Yea, sure - building a setup to test this. Did you actually `var_dump` the output to make shure you ain't got the comma or white spaces?

Comment: @kaiser - Hmm... no. but i didn't thought it is needed. if you'll have info that says otherwise from your text, i will be more than glad to hear :)

Comment: Please test it. Q/A formats always need work from both sides :)

Comment: @kaiser - do you have an HowTo on debugging? cause i'm having hard time to find how to use the var_dump in wordpress... never used it before - ever... :o

Comment: WP is coded in php, so you can use every native php function as usual.

Comment: o.k. yes, i know that. but i don't understand where i need to call the var_dump, and which variable i need to use it on... sorry. can you point me? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a WP specific solution, but you can usually set-up an alias/forwarder in your email system that sends a copy to both people.

e.g.

timandjoe@domain.com

sales@domain.com

etc.

Comment: yes. but's that isn't always possible. let say, when the host is lousy and won't let me manage my emails properly...

Comment: If you have a lousy host it's probably time to move hosts, not route around their lousiness ;-). This is certainly easier than a code based solution (for non technical users).

Comment: Yes, I know. but just for the challange. what would you do. in the end i've changed hosting and forward the Email as you suggested, and as I also thought would be the best solution. But what if?

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion, albeit a sorta hack, I'd like to make is to use a mailing list. You can add an infinite number of emails to a mailing list.

An alternative you could do is to use the [`publish_{$posttype}`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5688/custom-post-type-edit-publish-hook) hook to send email notificiations through [`wp_mail`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_mail?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/pluggable.php). The [`wp_mail`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_mail?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/pluggable.php) function's `$to` parameter takes either a string or an array so you could pass in multiple email addresses.

**EDIT:**

```
function notify_users_of_new_post($post_id) {
    // Get list of subscribers and their secondary email address stored in wp_usermeta
    $user_query = get_users('blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=subscriber&fields=all_with_meta');

    $bName = get_bloginfo('name');
    $permalink = get_permalink($post_id);
    foreach($user_query as $user) {
        $email = $user->email;

        if (isset($user->secondary_email) AND !empty($user->secondary_email)) {
            $email = array( $user->email, $user->secondary_email );
        }

        wp_mail($email, sprintf('New Blog Entry on %s', $bName), sprintf('A new entry has been published to %s. View it clicking here: %s', $bName, $permalink));
    }
}
add_action('publish_post', 'notify_users_of_new_post');
```

I attempted a sample code block (above). A suggestion if you plan on using this on a production site, use a cron job if you have a lot of registered users, otherwise I'm pretty sure this will cause a timeout in PHP.

Comment: Attempted a codeblock. Though I'm unfamiliar with these functions `get_users` (confused by Codex's query `$args`) and `wp_mail` by simply not having used it before.